# Преобразование BMP в JPEG в памяти на C++

Tags: c++, bitmap, jpeg, gdi+

Есть переменная `LPBYTE Buffer`, которая указывает на полноценный BMP файл, полученный в результате работы веб-камеры и кода формирования этого файла из кадра. Нужно преобразовать этот буфер в другой буфер с jpeg файлом, прямо в памяти - BMP жёсткого диска не касался, и jpeg-у этого тоже делать не надо.

**Подскажите пожалуйста алгоритм конвертации, или цепочку GDI+ вызовов (только без чтения/записи файлов).**

*PS: если записать этот BMP (226 Кб) на диск, открыть через paint и сохранить как jpg, этот jpg будет всего 13 Кб - вот такая нужна компрессия. Paint использует GDI+?*

Comment: Вообще то, вместо записи в файл, можно писать в память :)

Comment: Я не особо знаком с GDI+, а все найденные в сети примеры демонстрируют конвертацию при работе с файлами. Не просветите?

Comment: Берите готовую библиотеку a la [libjpeg](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/). [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) это умеет, думаю, что Qt тоже. Самостоятельно такое, думаю, вряд ли раскрутить получится...

Comment: Libjpeg это конечно здорово, но во-первых нужно получить её статические библиотеки для MinGW, и во-вторых вопрос - насколько раздуется exe-шник при статической линковке?

Comment: А покажите примеры. Наверняка можно и переделать под компрессию в памяти.

Comment: @Iceman, увы сейчас не смогу, меня тащат кататься с горки :). Гляньте на всякие "winapi-file-mapping". Я давно не работал с с++, а в с# это делается с помощью всяких MemoryStream. Я уверен, что подобное есть и в с++.

Comment: @VladD, например вот - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948280/gdi-converting-bitmap-pixels-to-jpg-format

Comment: @Iceman: Ну вот же [`Image::Save`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535406(v=vs.85).aspx), сохраняющий в поток. И там же рядом в соседнем ответе ссылка на [`CreateStreamOnHGlobal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378980(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Жесть какая-то... И Gdi, и Ole32... Зачем дополнительно IStream, когда уже есть готовый BMP в памяти? Короче, собрал Libjpeg - вроде не много весит статическая библиотека, попробую её средства.